# Can't set rootviewcontroller for modal segue'd UINavigationController

Tags: ios

I can't seem to follow Ray Wenderlichs tutorial on setting up modal segues - http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1 My subclass of SlideNavController is:

```
SlideNavController2.h
@interface SlideNavControlle2 : SlideNavController
```

Subclass of

```
SlideNavController.h
@interface SlideNavController : UIViewController
```

In app delegate I have the following:

```
SlideNavController2 *rootController = (SlideNavController2 *)
    self.window.rootViewController;

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[rootController
                                                 viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

diaryEntry *diaryEntry = [[navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
```

Off of a view controller (which has a class of SliderNavController2) I have a modal segue with a destination to a UINavigationController  which helps with my navigation for a UITableViewController (diaryEntry)

The Error I'm receiving is:

No visible @interface for 'SlideNavController2' declares the selector 'viewControllers'

Can anybody help me fix this error? Regards

Answer (score 1):

It means you SlideNavController2 doesn't implement viewControllers selector
Change this:

```
@interface SlideNavController : UIViewController
```

To this:

```
@interface SlideNavController : UINavigationController
```

This should fix your issue, and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had overlooked the tutorial completely when compared to my project. I was trying to search for viewControllers from SlideNavcontroller which doesn't come with viewcontrollers by default. My issue was that I had childviewcontrollers and I was searching for viewcontrollers.